# sql server db trigger when certain field changes

Tags: sql-server, triggers

is there anyway to put a condition in a SQL server trigger to say fire when field "XYZ" changes ?

**EDIT:**

what is the correct SQL syntax to basically insert into a new field

```
Field XZY has changes from Value A to value B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the trigger will always fire but you can break it's execution by using [UPDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) and [COLUMNS_UPDATED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) methods inside the trigger

Answer (score 2):

you can have a conditional section anywhere within your trigger statement using

```
IF UPDATE (column_name)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT column_name FROM INSERTED) = 'B'
    BEGIN
        /* do something */
    END
END
```